# How to give an OpenShift User read only permissions to everything?

Tags: openshift, okd

On an install of OKD I want to give a user permission to view absolutely any resource that is available via the API. As far as I can tell, my best option is to create a user and perform 
`oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-reader <user>` to give the user cluster-reader role.

However, it is still not clear to me from reading the documentation that this user can access absolutely everything available from the 145 GET endpoints [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/rest_api/openshift_v1.html) and 116 endpoints [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/rest_api/kubernetes_v1.html)

In one example, I have the admin do GET on /oapi/v1/clusterpolicies and receive

> {   "kind": "Status",   "apiVersion": "v1",   "metadata": {
>
> },   "status": "Failure",   "message": "the server could not find
>   the requested resource",   "reason": "NotFound",   "details": {
>
> },   "code": 404

However, when I have the user I created just to add cluster-reader to, performing the same call with that user returns:

> {   "kind": "Status",   "apiVersion": "v1",   "metadata": {
>
> },   "status": "Failure",   "message": "clusterpolicies is
>   forbidden: User \"\" cannot list
>   clusterpolicies at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched",
>   "reason": "Forbidden",   "details": {
>       "kind": "clusterpolicies"   },   "code": 403

Are examples such as these just a difference in error codes for resources that are non-existent anyway, or are there roles I am missing for my user if I truly want it to read absolutely everything?